# $a\neq b\in S$ versus $a,b\in S$, $a\neq b$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the statements:

1. $a\neq b\in S$
2. $a,b\in S$, $a\neq b$

Are these notations equivalent? I.e., if I consider statement 1, are the distinct elements $a$ and $b$ both in $S$?

Comment: Did you see the first notation somewhere?

Comment: Yes, a colleague of mine used this for a guest lecture, which got me confused. Hence my question.

Comment: And did that colleague mean it as: 'the logic statement $a \not = b$ is not in the set $S$'? Or do you think it was shorthand for what 2 is saying?  Do you remember the specific context?

Comment: It was about two distinct vertices being part of a graph, so it should have been what 2 signifies.

Comment: Yeah, I figured.  I know I have used this shorthand before ... but as Bob1123  says, that's really bad practice, because technically it means what Laars says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The second statement says both $a$ and $b$ are elements of $S$ while the first only makes sense if $S$ is a Boolean set.

Answer (score 0):

You may see statement 1 written to mean statement 2, but generally this is considered bad practice. Statement 2 is certainly less ambiguous.